# It's possible to flag a question as off-topic and very low quality through H&I

Tags: bug, flags, low-quality-posts, help-improvement

Today I was reviewing in the Help and Improvement review queue, and I clicked the "question is very low quality" button on one of the items I was reviewing. There are certain cases where VLQ flags can't be raised (being a day old, already in certain review queues, etc), so I opened the post, opened the flag dialog, and found that no VLQ flag had been raised. It looked like this:

[image]

I then proceeded to flag for closure. It worked as expected, and the dialog looked like this:

[image]

Then I checked my flagging history for that question, and found that I had somehow flagged the question as Very Low Quality *and* Should Be Closed.

[image]

I don't think users are supposed to be able to have multiple pending flags on the same post at the same time, yet this example appears to have gone against that.

Is there a deeper meaning behind this, or is it a bug?

Comment: So, just to be clear, you clicked the VLQ link in H&I? Did you get an error? What prompted you to go to the Q itself and flag for closure?

Comment: I noticed this as well but I always thought that being able to raise different types of flags for the same post was a (deliberate) *feature* not a *flaw*.

Comment: @Machavity yes, I clicked the "question is very low quality" link, andI didn't get any errors, just the normal "really flag this as VLQ?" confirmation dialog. I always check the question after using the button because VLQ flags can't always be cast (I can't find a source at the moment), and I want to flag for closure if not VLQ.

Comment: @LogicalBranch it is a feature to be able to raise multiple flags on the same post, but I'm pretty sure it's unintentional to be able to have multiple *pending* flags on the same post at once.

Comment: A post can have multiple flags by the same user at the same time as long as they are not the same flagtype group.